# Average number of customers at the service facility of an M/M/1/S queueing system

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains, queueing-theory

My [textbook](https://research.iaun.ac.ir/pd/daneshvar_farzanegan/pdfs/UploadFile_2042.pdf) (pg 121, formula 4.39) says:

> The average number of customers at the service facility:
> $N_S = P[k=0]E[N_S|k=0] + P[k>0]E[N_S|N>0] = 1 - P_0 = \rho(1-P_S)$

But I can't understand why this formula give this result (and I think that there is an error in  it). Can someone help me and explain please? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of customers *at the service facility* is always either $0$ or $1$. It is $0$ if there are no customers in the system at all; otherwise, it is $1$.

I think the formula should read
$$
   \color{red}{\mathbb{E}}[N_s] = \Pr[\color{red}{N}=0] \cdot \mathbb E[N_s \mid \color{red}{N}=0] + \Pr[\color{red}{N}>0] \cdot \mathbb E[N_s \mid N>0]
$$
where $ \mathbb E[N_s \mid N=0]$ simplifies to $0$ and $\mathbb E[N_s \mid N>0]$ simplifies to $1$. The conclusion is that $$\mathbb E[N_s] = \Pr[N>0] = 1 - \Pr[N=0] = 1 - P_0.$$ Presumably, the relation $1-P_0 = \rho(1-P_S)$ is proven earlier in the text.

Comment: Many thanks, now it makes sense. 
Yes, the last relation cames out from Saturation Probability: $P_S = (P_0 + \rho -1)/\rho$